# Is there a way to eliminate the "\" in frequently used LaTeX commands?

Tags: macros, substitution

The "\" in all of the commands requires frequent finger gymnastics of the pinky of the right hand in LaTeX, at least for the touch typist.  It occurred to me that although it makes things more readable via syntax highlighting, it certainly slows things down.

So, is there a way to, for certain often used commands, to eliminate the "\"?

For instance to type: `textit{some text here}`; `textbf{some more text here}`; `quotation{some text here}`; `item` instead of `\textit`; `\textbf`; `\quotation`; `\item` etc.

Not that I really mind stretching my right pinky frequently.

Comment: How should LaTeX know that you mean the word item in context `This item is a weird question` instead of the command form `\item` or in your version: `item`? Or `quotation`? On a US - Keyboard layout the backslash character is left to the `Enter` key, so this is not really a finger breaking procedure ;-)

Comment: Also, are you able and willing to run LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico: What solution does LuaLaTeX have to offer?

Comment: One can do this by making _everything_ active (so called 'ActiveTeX'), which has from time to time seemed attractive to various people. Life gets tricky as @ChristianHupfer  notes when you get down to the fact that TeX is about typesetting, so we have text as well as code.

Comment: I don't recommend this, regardless whether possible or not,but it's my personal opinion, of course

Comment: ...or redefine the (utterly useless *as is*) Caps Lock key to give `\ `. Voilá. (not for me, my Caps Lock is Compose, but well — I find the US keyboard `\ ` very handy. to the point I redefine my Spanish keyboard to move the `\ ` where it is in the US one).

Comment: @user1129682 - I've provided an answer that implements a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

Comment: On German keyboards (Mac) it’s Shift-Alt-7 to get a `\ `. Now *that* is becoming a serious problem when writing LaTeX documents for a longer amount of time.

Comment: To be clear, the keyboard layout I was complaining about is not the old Model M, which indeed had a very convenient \ key, but the newer one which I have laid out like this  http://www.knizefamily.net/russ/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/keyboard-model-m-1.jpg

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu On the Italian keyboard, it's the button next to the number 1 , below Esc. It does sound tedious to use it with a 3-button combination.

Comment: You may wish to consider preprocessing your document with pandoc. You can write simple commands in markdown, and still fallback to latex for more sophisticated macros

Comment: @Aditya great suggestion.

Comment: Protip: don't use your pinky for typing. Use your 4th finger.

Comment: @Cyoce Just kidding, right? Well, unless you don't *have* a pinky.  Oh, Thumb and other 4.  See, that's why I got an edjucayshun.

Comment: (remark: I remember reading somewhere that historically Knuth originally intend to use just "special keyword", but then decide against it and use the ``\``. I can't remember where I read it though)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Escape category code for other character

The escape character, which starts commands is not fixed and can be changed, e.g.:

```
\catcode`\|=0 % escape category code as the backslash
|textit{some text here}; |textbf{some more text here};
|begin{quotation}...|end{quotation}
```

The tricky part is finding the right character, which does not clash with other uses of it. It depends on the keyboard layout and the characters already used in the text.

If `_` is used, then the subscript feature in math mode is available via command `\sb` (or then `_sb`).

### Post-processing

Another way is to post-process the input file with a regular expression, which
checks for known command words, ensure that no letter is preceding or following and adds the backslash in front. For example, a simple expression for Perl:

```perl
s/\b(textbf|textit|item)\b/\\$1/g;
```

Comment: The `|` character is on the same key as `\\` so this does not prevent the finger stretching (I know, that this is an example only)

Comment: Yes, this depends on your keyboard layout.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer On my keyboard, the | and \ are on opposite sides. It simply depends on the keyboard layout, which differs between languages.

Comment: @Sverre: As I stated (basically) in my comment below the question: Using a US keyboard layout it's the same key ;-) I use US layout for programming and TeXing and German for mails (in German).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your comment below the question does not say that | and \ are on the same key on a US keyboard. It says that \ is left of the Enter key :)

Comment: Thank you everyone who commented, and of course for the answer.  I  designated the / key to be used in this manner, no shift nor stretch needed.  I noticed the / key still works.  On my US layout keyboard the \ is above the enter key, just under the backspace key.

Comment: Joseph Wright's mention of activeTEX is really interesting. I found a link: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb20-3/tb64fine.pdf

Answer (score 29):

Thinking outside the \box: instead of looking for a TeX solution, look for a general solution. You want to type X for Y. That's what editors excel at. Well, the good ones at least.

The *best* one is, of course, `vi` (or `vim` or `gvim`), a touch-typist's dream come true. You could, for example, remap the backslash to a key that's more easily reached.

```
imap # \
```

Or, if that interferes with other documents you write, selectively use insert-mode *abbreviations* such as

```
iabbr textit \textit
```

It's easy to restrict such mapping to files with a `.tex` extension only.

Comment: +1. Don't change LaTeX, change your editor or keyboard layout. Altering the syntax of the language can bite you in many ways (collaborators, code reuse, copy-and-pasting code to and from other sources...). Especially with a language that is as quirky to parse as LaTeX.

Comment: This could be the start of a very interesting Vim plugin.

Comment: If I used vim this would be wonderful.  But I use emacs, usually in org-mode, and I am beginner user.  I have not explored using emacs as my LaTeX editor though.  Will emacs do similar remapping and substitution?

Comment: @AFeldman somethin' in the .emacs file I think would do, like `(defun (backslash () (interactive) (insert (kbd "\\"))) (global-set-key (kbd ";" ) 'backslash)` or whatever

Comment: @doed thanks.  I love emacs.  Unfortunately my current TeX workflow doesn't allow for its use regularly.

Answer (score 8):

(Edited answer significantly to provide further generality)

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution that lets you omit the `\` (backslash) character from sectioning commands, `\begin{<some environment>}`, `\end{<some environment>}`, `\item`, and font shape-changing commands such as `\textit`, `\bfseries`, `\scshape`, and `\ttfamily`. Writing the backslash character is permitted, but not required. Note that no substitute for `\` needs to be entered.

There are but a few syntax rules:

- `section` and `subsection` directives *must* be placed at the *start* of a line.
- `item` instructions must be the first items (pun intended) on a line other than (possibly) whitespace.
- Finally, if you have created macros ill-advisedly named `\bend`, `\fend`, `\lend`, `\send` or `\tend`, they must not take arguments -- so that they can be distinguished from `\end`! Please don't create macros named, say, `\xxtextrm` or `\zzitshape` unless you want to make the Lua code below unfit for use.

---

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function add_backslash ( x )
  -- sectioning commands
  x = string.gsub ( x , "^\\?(section)"          , "\\%1" )
  x = string.gsub ( x , "^\\?(subsection)"       , "\\%1" )
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(subsubsection%s-{)" , "\\%1" )
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(paragraph%s-{)"     , "\\%1" )
  -- \begin and \end of environments
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(begin%s-{)"      , "\\%1" )
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(end%s-{)"        , "\\%1" )
  -- \item 
  x = string.gsub ( x , "^%s-\\?(item)"       , "\\%1" )
  -- \text?? (rm, sf, up, bf, it, ...)
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(text[^e]%l)"     , "\\%1" )
  -- \??shape (it, sc, ...)
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(%l[^e]shape)"    , "\\%1" )
  -- \??series (bf, md, ...)
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(%l%lseries)"     , "\\%1" )
  -- \??family (sf, tt, ...)
  x = string.gsub ( x , "\\?(%l%lfamily)"     , "\\%1" )
return x
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", add_backslash, "add_backslash")
\end{luacode*}

begin {document} 

section{Here}    
subsection {today,}    
 subsubsection   {gone}
   paragraph {tomorrow.}

begin{enumerate}
  item A
   item B
item C
end{enumerate}

 begin{equation}  1+1=2  end{equation}

  begin{itemize}
    item X is not equal to the following item:
    item Y
    item Z
  end{itemize}  

    begin{align} 
       a &= b\\
       c &= d
    end{align}

textit{abc}, textsc{def}, textbf{ghi}, textsf {jkl}

{itshape abc}, {scshape def}, {bfseries ghi}, {sffamily jkl}

end{document}
```

Note the complete absence of any and all backslash characters after the `\end{luacode*}` directive. I must confess that this code looks positively spooky to me.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you reshape something after a reply from somebody you texted earlier?

Comment: @cfr - I don't know what to say. Is your comment aimed at something I wrote or did?

Comment: If you typeset my comment in the environment, won't it think that contains two commands? Or have I misunderstood the syntax of Lua's regex expressions?

Comment: @cfr - Ah, now I get it. Let me narrow down the scope of some of the pattern-matching expressions.

Answer (score 5):

In the end I found myself agreeing with Federico Poloni and Rmano, that it is better to reassign keys. The `\` key on my keyboard is just to the left of the `Shift` key, so I swapped the `/` key with the `\` key using my  `~/.Xmodmap` file, using `xev` to determine the keycode and keysym for each as per [Swapping the left Alt and Ctrl keys in Ubuntu 11.10](https://earthviaradio.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/swapping-the-left-alt-and-ctrl-keys-in-ubuntu-11-10/)

In ubuntu 14.04, with this http://www.knizefamily.net/russ/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/keyboard-model-m-1.jpg as my keyboard, I added the following to my .Xmodmap file:

```
keycode 61 = backslash bar

keycode 51 = slash question
```

Beware though if you use this key for passwords, in a X Window dependent terminal, like gnome terminal, it also remaps the key for that terminal. This might cause a bit of consternation if it happens to be part of your sudo password.  This does not happen in a real terminal.

For the Mac user I understand that the same thing can be accomplished with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en).

Comment: Why don't you simply make use of automatic completion? You would obtain \begin{figure} by typing bfig and pressing esc (in TeXShop, but other editor allow auto completion)

Comment: esc on my keyboard is even further away than the \ key.

Comment: Sure, but you could hit 5 keys (namely "B F I G Esc") to get \begin{figure}. insted of 13+4 keys (B E G I N Alt+Shift+è F I G U R E Alt+Shift++).
Maybe you could change the key to get autocompletion, but I don't know every editors..

Comment: I have never used auto-complete.  I think it is because in order to use it you have to look at what it has auto-completed on the screen, make sure that it is right, then push Enter.  I realize that this becomes automatic after a while, when you become familiar with your auto-complete items.

Comment: As you do, I agree with Federico Poloni and Rmano: leave LaTeX unchanged - reassign keys. Anyway, as you pointed out, the use of auto-completion is just a matter of getting used to, so I suggest you to take advantage of this tool ;)