# What is the programming term for the command invoking '\' in latex?

Tags: macros, tex-core, latex-misc

I don't think it would be called a delimiter. Is there a specific term for this character?

Just to clarify, I'm talking the slash here:

```
\frac{1}{2}
```

Comment: Typesetting is `\textbackslash`, its definition is  `\escapechar` (more or less used in the TeX/LaTeX core only), so it's the escape character

Comment: Haha, no I'm not looking to insert the backslash character into an equation. I just want to know the term for what that primitive does in latex. Not sure if I'm being clear.

Comment: Apparently it's not clear

Comment: Okay. Lets say latex chose a different primitive to invoke the `frac` function. It could be `$frac` or `!frac`. The question is, what is the term for that primitive which invokes the function `frac`? Is it called an invoker? A delimiter? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for this phenomenon is [stropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stropping_(syntax))

Answer (score 31):

Not any character or action is available from a keyboard input as such an escaping to the 'TeX' system is necessary to typeset certain symbols or trigger actions -- in order to distinguish the text "foo" from a an action (call it macro etc.) named "foo" as well a certain method is necessary.

D.E. Knuth designed `\` to be `\` the “escape char” and is used to “escape” to commands, i.e. generate certain actions either in full macros, control words like `\foo` or as a control symbol like `\#` etc. to display special characters that itself have a special meaning (a different catcode, such as `#` or `$` etc.).

The escape character has been assigned the catcode `0`.

D.E. Knuth states in *The TeXBook* (see chapter 3, 3rd. paragraph, but see chapter 7 also):

> TeX allows any character to be used for escapes, but the 'backslash'
>   character '\' is usually adopted for this purpose, since backslashes
>   are reasonably convenient to type and they are rarely needed in
>   ordinary text. Things work out best when different TeX users do things
>   consistently, so we shall escape via backslashes in all examples of
>   the this manual.

Basically, any character could serve as escape character, i.e. having the meaning of “catcode 0”, see the example below -- but I don't recommend it. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\catcode`?=0

$?frac{1}{2}$

?section{Foo}

\end{document}
```

Even this is possible -- but don't do it (at least, I don't recommend this!)

```
\catcode`?=0

?documentclass{article}


?begin{document}

$?frac{1}{2}$

?section{Foo}

?end{document}
```

Related question: [*Is there a way to eliminate the “\” in frequently used LaTeX commands?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283713/is-there-a-way-to-eliminate-the-in-frequently-used-latex-commands)

Here's a short overview of characters with must be escaped with `\`:

```
\ { } $ & # ^ _ % ~
```

all require a `\` to be typeset directly, i.e. use

```
\\ \{ \} \$ \& \# \^ \_ \% \~
```

Comment: `\escapechar` is more like the symbol that *prints* when `\string` (or `\detokenize`) is used; at least I would put it that way. The character used to escape is any character that has `\catcode` 0.

Comment: @Manuel: You're right. I removed the the backslash and call it literally `escape char`

Comment: @AFeldman: Posting bad code get's a lot of phraises :D

Comment: Posting "weird questions" also does.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just curious, why is it called catcode? If I called the primitive 'the catcode', would this make sense? Or does it only make sense when I call it the 'escape char'?

Comment: @Akiva: `category codes` are used to let `TeX` act in different modes, i.e. enter math mode with `$` or begin group /end group `{...}` characters. `The catcode` would be wrong.

Comment: Humm... Obfuscated (La)TeX contests, anyone?  But I wonder what would happen with packages?  That is, they're written with '\' internally, but the file that uses them redefines that to '!'.

Comment: @jamesqf: Of course, it's not compatible -- that's why I said it's not recommended. If somebody designs a TeX format of his/her own and provides the relevant setup or packages/external files for this, it's another story then. In this case anything is possible.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I don't know that "of course" really follows.  I can think of ways that TeX might make it work, doing something like saving state, or internally equating '\' as '!' in loaded packages.  But I know nothing about how TeX actually does work, internally, so I asked :-)

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't think it is possible (or at least not very easy!) to replace `\` by something on the fly.